# The send function states that it is looking for type. Still don't think code is accurate

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

So I ran this code and it worked but changed location.  The information stated that within the quote should be a type inside the xmlRequest.send().  In either case I need to run the code and could look at another look.

```
function doGet (originalMeasure, convertMeasure){
              var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              myFunction(this);
              var str = originalMeasure;
              var requestString = str.replace(/\s/g, '+');
              requestString.concat('+in+', 'convertMeasure');
              xmlRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.gooogle.com/search?q=' + requestString, 'false');
              xmlRequest.send(null);
              var largerThanOne = parseInt(str);
              if (largerThanOne != 1)
              {
              string.index(str+"s=");
              var whereIsIt = request.responseText;
              }
              else if (largerThanOne = 1)
              {
              string.index(str+"=");
              var whereIsIt = request.responseText;
              }
              }
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive.... you misspelled `xmlhttprequest` and can look it up easily yourself. Also can't process the response unitl it is returned as it is an asynchronous request. Lots of tutorials around on how to do this

Comment: Also strings don't have a `.push()` method.

Comment: @charlietfl I believe that I was pretty specific in my paragraph above on what I was looking, so isn't the hold a little overkill.  I believe you guys just hit that button to hit it when you don't wish to respond to something.  I gave you where the error is and you could ask, as adults I must add, as to what the issue is and I will explain again where it is.  But instead you place it on hold as children.  You guys who write script act smart.. But in turn you aren't, you are socially incompatible.

Comment: @JoelFrick you didn't even mention what the specific error was....and most errors are easily searched in google. Writing code is only part of programming....learning how to use built in debugging tools and doing research is equally as important and unfortunataely is often time consuming

Comment: @charlietfl so me stating it had an error on line 4 column 14 it didn't give you where the error was.  Are you serious right now or lack the ability to read?

Comment: @JoelFrick how about the lack of ability to provide what the specific error was....those messages have a meaning and are important. Most of your issue is simply being too lazy to do the research needed. Once the first error is fixed you will also have others .. each requiring a fix

Comment: Lets see.. CMD prompt doesn't provide a bunch but I pretty well provided you the problem but it states there should be an open quote on that area.  But if you know code shouldn't you be able to see where the problem is?  So what your saying is you don't know code.

Comment: Yup...that's it....and we are also here as servants to your every need too. Why so arrogant when mentioning that the actual erro message is important? *"give a man a fish, or teach a man to fish"*??

Comment: No I am asking for people to assist, not block a question they can't answer.  You have to teach a man to fish before they know how to fish, but how are you teaching or providing the hook when you block a response.  People are new to coding, like myself, and I looked up every answer I provided, I didn't have a book.  So I already did a bunch of leg work and now am stuck that is where I was looking for assistance.  But I get people who think there heads are in clouds that they can't assist.

Comment: So what is the actual error? (teach a man to read errors) And which is line 4? That line may not even reference the code shown. 4th line is `var str = 'orginalMeasure';` which is innocuous

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define:

`var originalMeasure, convertMeasure;`

Because those variables are already being passed into your method.

`var xmlRequest = new xmlhttprequest();`

Should be:

`var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Notice the capital letters.

Unless I'm mistaken, this line: `requestString.push('+in+', 'convertMeasure')` is using a mehtod that doesn't exist. I think you are looking for:

`requestString.concat('+in+', 'convertMeasure')`

Also, you have:

```
var Url = 'http://www.gooogle.com/search?q=' + 'requestString'
```

Which means you are appending the string 'requestString` to the end of the url, you want to append the actual variable:

```
var Url = 'http://www.gooogle.com/search?q=' + requestString;
```

You did that in a couple places:

`var str = 'orginalMeasure';` -> `var str = originalMeasure;`

Notice the spelling correction as well. Variable names, types and method names need to match exactly, so be careful with spelling and capitalization.

Start with those and see if you find more errors. I suggest you find a good code editor that does syntax highlighting, because it would catch some of your missing semi-colons and things like that for you.

Comment: It's unnecessary but harmless.

Comment: @Alex R I did those revisions and it still has a problem with line 4 column 14.